# Using configurable string in enum description

Tags: c#, .net, enums, configuration, config

I am running two instances of the same application with some small differences in each of them.

More precisely, I would like to keep the same enums but have them use different descriptions that would be configurable from one instance to the other.

I've tried the following :

```
public enum myEnum
    {

        [Description(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["value1Desc"])]
        value1 = 1,
        [Description(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["value2Desc"])]
        value2 = 2
    }
```

But it requires a constant. How could I make the descriptions configurable from one instance to the other without having to make changes inside the code itself?

Any clean suggestions ?

Comment: You could do so via T4 templates

Comment: I find myself somewhat suspicious of a design problem if a compile-time name for a numeric value needs to have two different meanings in the same application.

Comment: How are you using this description? Why does it need to be different depending on the application? I agree with the previous comment...there's a smell here. But why can't you just store e.g. `"value1Desc"` and `"value2Desc"` in the attribute, and then use that value to look up the actual value for the description? Frankly, the question is very vague and hence too broad.